# Extract N last non-empty cells of each row using SAS

Tags: null, sas, extract

Trying to extract last 3 non empty cells of a row using SAS

Data have:

```
Order_ID,Fruit1,Fruit2,Fruit3,Fruit4,Fruit5
1234,Banana,Peach,Guava,Apple,,
1235,Orange,Grape,,,,
1236,Pear,Papaya,Apricot,,,
1237,Guava,,,,,
1238,Kiwi,Cherry,Peach,Melon, Lime
```

Data want:

```
Order_ID,Fruit1,Fruit2,Fruit3,
1234,Peach,Guava,Apple,
1235,Orange,Grape,,
1236,Pear,Papaya,Apricot,
1237,Guava,,,
1238,Peach,Melon,Lime
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
data have;
  infile cards dlm="," missover;
  length Order_ID 8 Fruit1-Fruit5 $ 10;
  input Order_ID (Fruit1-Fruit5) (:$);
cards;
1234,Banana,Peach,Guava,Apple,,
1235,Orange,Grape,,,,
1236,Pear,Papaya,Apricot,,,
1237,Guava,,,,,
1238,Kiwi,Cherry,Peach,Melon, Lime
;
run;
proc print;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array f{*} $ Fruit:; 
  array last[3] $ 10;

  j = 3;
  do i = dim(f) to 1 by -1;
    if not missing(f[i]) then
      do;
        last[j]=f[i];
        j+(-1);
      end;
    if 0=j then leave;
  end;

  call missing(of f[*]);
  j=0;
  do i = 1 to 3;
    if not missing(last[i]) then
      do;
        j+1;
        f[j]=last[i];
      end;
  end;

  keep Order_ID Fruit1-Fruit3;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

and read about SAS arrays, for example [here](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/97529_Using_Arrays_in_SAS_Programming.pdf) or [here](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug02/bt/bt002.pdf).

---

An alternative approach would be to use [*SAS Packages Framework*](https://github.com/yabwon/SAS_PACKAGES) and [*BasePlus*](https://github.com/SASPAC/baseplus) package, which contains [`arrMissToLeftC()`](https://github.com/SASPAC/baseplus/blob/main/baseplus.md#arrmisstoleftc-subroutine) function.

```
filename packages "%sysfunc(pathname(work))"; /* setup WORK as temporary directory for packages */
filename SPFinit url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yabwon/SAS_PACKAGES/main/SPF/SPFinit.sas";
%include SPFinit; /* enable the framework */

%installPackage(BasePlus) /* install BasePlus package */
%loadPackage(BasePlus, cherryPick=arrMissToLeftC) /* load selected function from the package into the SAS session */

options cmplib=work.basePlusFCMP;

data _null_;
 set have ;
 array f{*} $ Fruit:;

 /*put "before: " (Fruit:) (=);*/
 call arrMissToLeftC(f);
 /*put "after:  " (Fruit:) (=);*/

 keep Order_ID Fruit3-Fruit5;
 rename
  Fruit3=Fruit1
  Fruit4=Fruit2
  Fruit5=Fruit3
 ;
run;
```

Comment: You can avoid `leave` test by adding a condition to the do loop. `do i = dim(f) to 1 by -1 while (j>0);`

Answer (score 1):

```
data have;
input Order_ID (Fruit1 - Fruit5)(:$);
infile datalines dlm = ',' missover;
datalines;
1234,Banana,Peach,Guava,Apple,,    
1235,Orange,Grape,,,,              
1236,Pear,Papaya,Apricot,,,        
1237,Guava,,,,,                    
1238,Kiwi,Cherry,Peach,Melon, Lime 
;

data want;
   set have;
   array f{*} Fruit:;
   n = dim(f) - cmiss(of f[*]);
   idx = (n - 3);

   if n > 3 then do i = 1 to n;
      if i + idx <= 5 then f[i] = f[i + idx];
   end;

   keep Order_ID Fruit1 - Fruit3;
run;
```

Comment: Excellent way! Peter, could you please explain how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

`catx` and `scan` can be used to simplify the logic for repositioning the k-th last non-missing items in an array.

Example:

Data has interspersed missing values that would use complicated index tracking in a  plain array based solution.  `catx` used to collapse those missings and have simpler indexing.

```
data have;
input Order_ID (Fruit1 - Fruit5)(:$);
infile datalines dsd dlm = ',' missover;
datalines;
1234,Banana,Peach,Guava,Apple,,
1235,Orange,Grape,,,,
1236,Pear,Papaya,Apricot,,,
1237,Guava,,Peach,,Cherry,
1238,Kiwi,Cherry,Peach,Melon, Lime
1239,Strawb
1240,Orange,,,,Grape
1241,
1242,,,Orange,Grape
;

/* want last k non-missing in first k slots */
%let k = 3;

data want;
   set have;
   array f Fruit:;

   s = catx(',', of f[*]);
   n = min(countw(s),&k);

   do j = 1 to &k;
     if n >= j 
       then f[j] = scan(s,j-1-n);
       else call missing(f[j]);
   end;
                                
   keep Order_ID Fruit1 - Fruit&k;
run;
```